# Creating an index of words

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to create an index of words, reading each line from a text file and checking to see if the word is in that line. If so, it prints out the number line and continues the check. I've gotten it to work how I wanted to when printing each word and line number, but I'm not sure what storage system I could use to contain each number.

Code example:

```
def index(filename, wordList):
    'string, list(string) ==> string & int, returns an index of words with the line number\
    each word occurs in'
    indexDict = {}
    res = []
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    count = 0
    line = infile.readline()
    while line != '':
        count += 1
        for word in wordList:
            if word in line:
                #indexDict[word] = [count]
                print(word, count)
        line = infile.readline()
    #return indexDict
```

This prints the word and whatever the count is at the time (line number), but what I'm trying to do is store the numbers so that later on I can make it print out

```
word linenumber

word2 linenumber, linenumber
```

And so on. I felt a dictionary would work for this if I put each line number inside a list so each key can contain more than one value, but the closest I got was this:

```
{'mortal': [30], 'dying': [9], 'ghastly': [82], 'ghost': [9], 'raven': [120], 'evil': [106], 'demon': [122]}
```

When I wanted it to show up as:

```
{'mortal': [30], 'dying': [9], 'ghastly': [82], 'ghost': [9], 'raven': [44, 53, 55, 64, 78, 97, 104, 111, 118, 120], 'evil': [99, 106], 'demon': [122]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want a defaultdict that defaults to a [] for new keys, and append. Your commented out line, of course, just re-writes the key with a 1-item list each time.

Comment: For everyone that answered, thank you for the input. It was very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the old value by this line

```
indexDict[word] = [count]
```

Changing it to

```
indexDict[word] = indexDict.setdefault(word, []) + [count]
```

Will yield the answer you want. It'll get the current value of indexDict[word] and append the new count to it, if there is no indexDict[word], it creates a new empty list and append count to it.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: @iKyriaki: The `defaultdict` solutions do the same thing, in a more compact syntax.

Comment: NP. You choose dictionary so I use a dictionary method to help you. I don't understand why some people rewrite your code using collections.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
import collections
def index(filename, wordList):
    indexDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for (i, line) in enumerate(infile.readlines()):
            for word in wordList:
                if word in line:
                    indexDict[word].append(i+1)
    return indexDict
```

This yields the exact same results as in your example (using Poe's Raven).

Alternatively, you might consider using a normal `dict` instead of a `defaultdict` and initialize it with all the words in the list; to make sure that the `indexDict` contains an entry even for words that are not in the text.

Also, note the use of `enumerate`. This builtin function is very useful for iterating over both the index and the item at that index of some list (like the lines in the file).

Comment: For line numbers, it makes sense to start with 1 instead of zero. You can do that with `enumerate(infile, 1)`, then later one `.append(i)`

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more pythonic way to write this, but just for readability you could try this (a simple example):

```
dict = {1: [], 2: [], 3: []}

list = [1,2,2,2,3,3]

for k in dict.keys():
    for i in list:
        if i == k:
            dict[k].append(i)


In [7]: dict
Out[7]: {1: [1], 2: [2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3]}
```

Comment: This would append the _lines_, not the line numbers!

Comment: I was using numbers just to show logic, thought there was already a line index value to append, 
"count += 1".  Lazys gonna laze.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append your next item to the list, if the list already exists.

The easiest way to have the list already be there even for the first time you find a word, is to use the [`collections.defaultdict` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to track your word-to-lines mapping:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def index(filename, wordList):
    indexDict = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for i, line in enumerate(infile):
            for word in wordList:
                if word in line:
                    indexDict[word].append(i)
                    print(word, i)

    return indexDict
```

I've simplified your code a little using best practices; opening the file as a context manager so it'll close automatically when done, and using `enumerate()` to create line numbers on the fly.

You could speed this up a little further still (and make it more accurate) if you turned your lines into a set of words (`set(line.split())` perhaps, but that won't remove punctuation), as then you could use set intersection tests against `wordList` (also a set), which could be considerably faster to find matching words.

Comment: What happened to your `count` variable? should htis: `indexDict[word].append(count)' be this 'indexDict[word].append(i)`? And what is `res` for?

Comment: Also, if you are going to be the only person who mentions `defaultdict`, you might also mention `collections.Counter`, although I don't understand the OP's use case well enough to tell if counting instances is the idea.

Comment: Bad editing; thanks for pointing those errors out. I considered mentioning `Counter` but dismissed it; it's API is overkill for this usecase.